# How to create a graph network from a DataFrame of coordinates in python?

Tags: python, gis

I have a DataFrame that contains two columns, one column is latitude and another one is longitude of locations on the map.
Also, I have coordinates of start and end points. (They are not in the DataFrame)

I want to create a graph network (matrix) directed between start and end point like the graph network schematic below.

[image: Graph Network Schematic]

```py
#Desired output
np.array([[0,1,1,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,1,1,0],
          [0,0,0,1,1,0],
          [0,0,0,0,1,1],
          [0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

I have tried this code so far:

```py
#start_df and end_df are DataFrames containing lat and lon of start and end points 

#location_inbetween containts lat and lon of points between start and end

graph_df = pd.concat([start_df,location_inbetween,end_df],axis=0)
graph_df.reset_index(inplace = True,drop = True)

 
a = np.zeros(shape=(graph_df.shape[0],graph_df.shape[0]))
graph_mat = pd.DataFrame(a)

for i in range(graph_df.shape[0]): 
    for j in range(graph_df.shape[0]): 
        test = ( abs(graph_df.iloc[i,1]) < abs(graph_df.iloc[j,1]) ) | ( abs(graph_df.iloc[i,0]) < abs(graph_df.iloc[j,0]) )  

        if test == True: 
            graph_mat.iloc[i,j] =  1
```

But it's not a good answer.

Comment: Tried anything?

Comment: Honestly, I don't have any idea to where to look and attack the question.

Comment: @hd1 I have a method that connect every dot but I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def First(graph_df):

graph_mat = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(graph_df.shape[0],graph_df.shape[0])))

for i in range(graph_df.shape[0]): 
    for j in range(graph_df.shape[0]): 
        test = ( abs(graph_df.iloc[i,1]) < abs(graph_df.iloc[j,1]) ) | ( abs(graph_df.iloc[i,0]) < abs(graph_df.iloc[j,0]) )  
        if test == True: 
            graph_mat.iloc[i,j] =  1

for i in range(graph_mat.shape[0]): 
    for j in range(graph_mat.shape[0]): 
        for k in range(graph_mat.shape[0]): 
            test1 = ( abs(graph_df.iloc[i,1]) < abs(graph_df.iloc[j,1]) ) &  ( abs(graph_df.iloc[j,1]) < abs(graph_df.iloc[k,1]) ) & ( abs(graph_df.iloc[i,1]) < abs(graph_df.iloc[k,1]) )
            test2 = ( abs(graph_df.iloc[i,0]) < abs(graph_df.iloc[j,0]) ) &  ( abs(graph_df.iloc[j,0]) < abs(graph_df.iloc[k,0]) ) & ( abs(graph_df.iloc[i,0]) < abs(graph_df.iloc[k,0]) )
            test3 = (graph_mat.iloc[i,j] == 1) & (graph_mat.iloc[j,k] ==1)
            test4 = test1 & test2 & test3 
            if test4 == True:
                graph_mat.iloc[i,k] = 0
return graph_mat
graph_mat = First(graph_df)
```